# How can I manage the Followers Activity log on Instagram?

Tags: instagram, follow

The Instagram smartphone application has an *Activity* log (represented by the heart button at the bottom of the screen) and this *Activity* log is divided into two tabs:

1. *You* that features the follow requests (for private accounts), who started to follow you and who likes your posts.
2. *Following* that shows (some) of the posts liked by people you are following, the comments they like and their answers.

I'd like to see what some posts of the people I am following like because we have similar interests (travel, food, fitness,...) but not all of them. Also, I don't care about all kind of information, for example, that someone liked a comment on their post. This leads to a lot of noise on the Following Activity log, even though I don't follow that many people. Some people with many followers tend to like every comment on their posts, so it is very common to have blocks of irrelevant information on the log.

**Is it possible to personalize what kind of information I see in the Following Activity log**?

Edit: Instagram decided to remove the Followers Activity log. Should I delete this answer?